# API key? Web scraping? arrest/jail records and court records? Im so lost

Tags: node.js, api, web-scraping

So, I'm currently doing a Web Dev bootcamp, I'm about halfway done and I'm trying to come up with a personal project to challenge myself and also have something useful that'll stand out. Anyways,

I have this odd hobby of monitoring everyone who's been arrested per week in Hillsborough County FL. Sometimes if I see an old friend who has been arrested, I immediately go to the clerk of court website for Hillsborough county and look at their court case and even get their CRA(Criminal Report Affidavit) aka Police Report redacted so I can see what they actually did. I'm really big into all of this, call it weird but I got sick of having to look up the arrest on florida.arrests.org or from
webapps.hcso.tampa.fl.us/ArrestInquiry and then having to go immediately to hover.hillsclerk.com to search court records and all court info regarding said person. I thought it'd be cool to construct a website where on the index page it's just 2 textboxes and 1 submit button. 1 text box being for First Name and the second being for Last Name. Once submitted, the First and Last Name are compared to a database and all arrests for Joe Macgyver come up and Joe Macgyver's court cases(open and closed) which include court dates, evidence submitted by the state, basically everything that happened in court on whatever day. So all arrests for Joe Macgyver in Hillsborough county come up and on the same page all court cases. I figured it'd be cool and it'd save me some time but I don't even know where to begin.

It looks like florida.arrests.org is gonna be more practical than webapps.hcso.tampa.fl.us/ArrestInquiry because they just recently made some changes and the sheriff's office is only allowing arrests within a 3 month time period to remain public record that can be accessed for free online. They also have a captcha that needs to be entered for every search done However, Florida.arrests logs every arrest made and doesn't delete anything and has records going back to the late 90s. I can't seem to find any way to get an API key for florida.arrests.org so I know its possible to do what i wanna do, I just dont know where to start and how to go about it. A friend suggested web scraping, I did some research and got a little confused. Can anyone possibly help point me in the right direction? I figured if I kept the searches down to only hillsborough county, it should make my idea a little easier.

Thank you,
SparklingCoffee

Comment: How is that illegal? It's all public information....

Comment: Your title is not sufficiently appropriate and it is better to change it.